# How to see where in my code a function gets called in RStudio?

Tags: r, ide, rstudio, call

I'm currenty cleaning up my first big R project and at a point, where I have a lot of functions implemented but I am not sure, which function got called and used by me in an other script and which function got never used. So now I want to get all calls of this function in my project. Is this possible? 
I'm using RStudio and a lot of other IDEs I've used got a feature like this, so I was wondering if this is also implemented in RStudio.
I searched the web and stack overflow, but got no answer, so I assume that this is not possible but I wanted to ask, just in case it IS possible but I didn't found the right answer.
Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you are just looking for profiling: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/218221837-Profiling-with-RStudio

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for :)